# How I choose float_format between ".xg" and ".xf" using Python?

Tags: python, format

I want to choose the best way to present a float number for the following rules:

```
input = 1500.000001
output = 1500

input = 1500.01
output = 1500.01

input = 1500
output = 1500
```

I try two methods, float_format = ".2g" and ".2f", but they all partly satisfied my rules.

if float_format = ".2g", output = 1.5e3

if float_format = ".2f", output = 1500.00

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand you correctly, I would use Decimal.

```
from decimal import Decimal
input = 1500.00001
as_decimal = Decimal(input).quantize(Decimal('0.01'))
>>> Decimal('1500.00')
```

Additionally you could check if it's an int or a float. So:

```
input = 1500
if type(input) == int:
    pass
elif type(input) == float:
    input = Decimal(input).quantize(Decimal('0.01'))
```

Comment: Thanks, I use the float_format during output a dataframe into csv file. I wrote format_type = '.2g' or '.2f', this setting is too complexed, I must reset the data in frame?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a dataframe here. Are you using pandas? I don't have any experience with pandas so I couldn't tell you what you want for that.